# Create a indexed list

Tags: associations

I am trying to create an indexed list with `Association[]` but i getting only a few keys when accesing a specific key.
Here is the code:

```
In[] :=series = Association[
      "white" -> 1,
      "white" -> 0,
      "blue" -> 2,
      "green" -> 1,
      "green" -> 2,
      "yellow" -> 3
      ]
 Out[] :=<|"white" -> 0, "blue" -> 2, "green" -> 2, "yellow" -> 3|>
```

And when I access the key "white" it only displays number 0, intead of 1 and 0.

```
 In[]:= series["white"]
 Out:= 0
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It needs to be done something like the following

```
Merge[Association /@ {"white" -> 1, "white" -> 0, "blue" -> 2, 
   "green" -> 1, "green" -> 2, "yellow" -> 3}, Join]
%["white"]
```

> {1, 0}

Answer (score 2):

It must be noted that Suba has a great approach, and shows the proper usage of `Merge` in their answer.

However, if can you make the `Association` applied to a `List`, or use a `List` in any way, there are approaches that I consider to be much simpler which I will show below.

Let's start with the messier version:

```
Extract[Transpose@{Range@Length@#}][#]&@Inactivate@Association["white" -> 1,
      "white" -> 0,
      "blue" -> 2,
      "green" -> 1,
      "green" -> 2,
      "yellow" -> 3]//GroupBy[#,Extract[1]->Extract[2]]&


(* <|"white" -> {1, 0}, "blue" -> {2}, "green" -> {1, 2}, 
 "yellow" -> {3}|> *)
```

However, the syntax begins to simplify if there is a list contained within the `Association`:

```
Extract[{1,1}]@Defer@Association[{"white" -> 1,
      "white" -> 0,
      "blue" -> 2,
      "green" -> 1,
      "green" -> 2,
      "yellow" -> 3}]//GroupBy[#,Extract[1]->Extract[2]]&


(* same as above *)
```

Finally, we can realize the cleanest looking implementation of this method, if we are able to use a `List` of the `Association`s:

```
GroupBy[
      {"white" -> 1,
      "white" -> 0,
      "blue" -> 2,
      "green" -> 1,
      "green" -> 2,
      "yellow" -> 3},Extract[1]->Extract[2]]


(* same as above *)
```

I hope this explains a possible set of alternatives. If you already defined `series` and wish to use that, unfortunately I cannot currently find a good workaround for that.

Please, let me know if you have any questions!